# Specific url parameter not working in Zend Framework 1.12.3

Tags: php, api, url, zend-framework

I'm using the Zend framework at version 1.12.3, and I'm having trouble with specific param on url.
The url is composite with the param called 'code':

api/callback?code=626e574a766c65534a43644167714768545544

But the framework is not readind the param 'code', if I change the param to 'cod' by example I can read it:

api/callback?cod=626e574a766c65534a43644167714768545544

The code on Zend is, and include works on others functions:
`$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();`

Comment: I don't think this is a ZFW thing. Have you stepped through the request with a debugger? Do you have any mod_rewrite things going on?

Comment: Do you mean about htaccess mod_rewrite? I can't change anything on this url, because it's a callback response.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Something is messing with your parameters and it's probably not Zend FW. If you can, step through with a debugger and see the if the `code` param is present, and if it is, where it gets dropped or changed to something else.

Comment: This is my htaccess, can you see any any inconsistence?

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Comment: What is in the array returned by  `$this->getRequest()->getParams()`? Is `code` not present at all, or is it an empty string, or zero?

Comment: This return is a status 200 and a blank page.

Comment: You're going to have to dig deeper and look at what's actually happening, there is no way do diagnose the problem using what you're provided. Look at the actual contents of the array returned by `getParams()` to see if the `code` param is present but set to somthing like an empty string, zero, or `false`. If that's the case, look for something in the application code that is manually setting the `code` parameter on the request to some kind of default. I can imagine a developer using the `code` param on the request to pass a status code through the routing of the request.

Comment: Or you could just `$code = $_GET['code'];`

Comment: We note that this behavior is only on logged requests, our solution was to start receiving the callback response in a url not logged in the system, in this way the parameter started to be read correctly, we are probably dealing with some reserved word or some internal treatment of Zend that we could not find. Thanks for the help.